# Why do jquery-ui addClass animation parameters have no effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css-animations

Goal: Animate a class change on element temporarily, fx change background color to BLUE then back to normal.

Approach: Add a class to an element for a specified time in ms with animtion using jquery ui's addClass method, then remove using removeClass.

Problem: The animation works just fine, but no matter what I do, the parameters for duration and easing have no effect. Why?

Alternate approaches are also welcome.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message");
var button = $("button");

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){

 // Temporarily change class
 //flashClass("alt", banner, { inTime: 2000, outTime:500, easeName:'swing'});
  
  // Try default method with long duration for adding class only
  banner.addClass( "alt", 2000, "swing" );
  
  // Try explicit version for adding class only
  /*
  banner.addClass( "alt", { 
   duration: 2000, 
    easing: "swing", 
    complete: function() {}, 
    children: false,
    queue: true    
    });
    */
    
  
    
})


 
 function flashClass(className, jqElem, transitionObj) {
  if(!(className && jqElem)) return false;
  if(!transitionObj) {
   transitionObj = {
     inTime: 500,
      outTime: 500,
      easeName: 'linear'
    }
  }
    
  jqElem.addClass(className, transitionObj.inTime, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
     jqElem.removeClass(className,transitionObj.outTime, null);
    }, 500);
  });  
 }
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just need a good callback. It will use `setTimeout()` to ensure it does not run right away.

```js
$(function() {
  // find elements
  var banner = $("#banner-message");
  var button = $("button");

  // handle click and add class
  button.click(function(e) {
    banner.addClass("alt", 2000, removeAlt);
  });

  function removeAlt(t) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      banner.removeClass("alt");
    }, 2001);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I already tried that with the flashclass() function above, but only the setTimout duration has an effect. banner.addClass("alt", 2000, removeAlt) still animates with a standard duration (fast), not with the "2000" as specified by the parameter.